# Facing issue while trying to run JSTL in a springboot project on Eclipse

Tags: spring-boot, jstl

in my `pom.xml`. I have

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>    
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

but still on running the JSP ,I am getting an error `The absolute uri: [https://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: [https://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application`

Can anyone help?

I tried many alternatives but nothing works